# haskell-postgres --> connect parameter is not a Query

Tags: postgresql, haskell

My program:

```
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple

main :: IO ()
main = do
  conn <- connect defaultConnectInfo
    { connectUser = "postgres"
      , connectPassword = "password"
      , connectDatabase = "postgres"
    }
  execute conn "create table users (id INT, fname VARCHAR(80), lname VARCHAR(80))" ()
  close conn
```

Error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Query’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    In the second argument of ‘execute’, namely
      ‘"create table users (id INT, fname VARCHAR(80), lname VARCHAR(80))"’
```

Does the user need to make the above psql string into a Query typed object and send it as a parameter to `connect` function? The tutorial is not written this way but the error is meaning otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.4.10.0/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html):

> To most easily construct a query, enable GHC's OverloadedStrings language extension and write your query as a normal literal string.

`OverloadedStrings` will let you write what appears to be a `String` and have GHC auto-coerce it to the appropriate type (`ByteString`, `Text`, `Query`).  It's a useful extension to keep in your toolbox.